# Why does One Plus Nord 2T 5G crash with Animation Error?

Tags: android, react-native, oneplusone

I am experiencing following issues with only One Plus Telephones. Does anyone have an idea what this might be?

I am having a hard to trying to figure out what causes this.

Can this have something to do with OnePlus Oxygen?
I haven't experienced this myself. This is logs from AppCenter.

`com.facebook.react.animated.FrameBasedAnimationDriver.runAnimationStep FrameBasedAnimationDriver.java, line 73 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calculated frame index should never be lower than 0`

```
com.facebook.react.animated.FrameBasedAnimationDriver.runAnimationStep FrameBasedAnimationDriver.java:73
com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.runUpdates NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:633
com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$1.doFrameGuarded NativeAnimatedModule.java:263
com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame GuardedFrameCallback.java:29
com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame ReactChoreographer.java:175
com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame ChoreographerCompat.java:85
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run Choreographer.java:1386
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run Choreographer.java:1396
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks Choreographer.java:1033
android.view.ChoreographerExtImpl.checkScrollOptSceneEnable ChoreographerExtImpl.java:397
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame Choreographer.java:900
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run Choreographer.java:1371
android.os.Handler.handleCallback Handler.java:942
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:99
android.os.Looper.loopOnce Looper.java:240
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:351
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:8321
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:584
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:1012
```

Answer (score 1):

this issue is fixed
check here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35766

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed - facebook/react-native@c05d822

Comment: I honestly don't see the point in posting this as an answer instead of just editing the other answer by Pratham